# Can the notation for polynomial reduction, A ≤p B be reversed in computability theory?

Tags: computability, notation

I don't know this is a proper question on this forum but I was reading about computability theory and I saw the reduction concept and its notation like this: $A \le_pB$. I just wanted to know is this notation can be reversed? that is, can I write this down like $A\ge_p B$ And still have a meaning? I searched a lot but this notation always been like the former and I got confused.

Comment: I have not encountered that notation before, so you should probably define it if you insist on using it. I'm not sure why you would want to write it down like this, but people will probably understand what you mean. (In fact, I personally find this notation a lot less clear than just natural language in most contexts)

Comment: $A \geq B$ is the same as $B \leq A$.

Comment: In response to discrete lizard:

it's about reducibility in the theory of computation

Comment: do you mean that A can be reduced to B in polynomial time?

Comment: Yes. can I say that in another way: like if I have A ≤p B, then can I say B ≥p A and still have the same meaning?

Comment: To echo @Discretelizard: of course you can (as long as you explain it), but why bother?

Comment: this is the reverse statement of the reduction in your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes. I am writing an essay about difficulties of computing in another language( Farsi) and as you know, the writing style in this language is from right to left. in addition. I wanted to write this concept in an informal manner. then searching about this concept and its notation led me to believe that there is one way to writing this notation. although as you guys told, I'm in error and I can reverse it.

Comment: You can reverse it if you want. To be pedantic: you can not rewrite $A \leq B$ as $A \geq B$, but only as $B \geq A$. In left-to-right languages, though, it is quite common to only use the notation $A \leq B$ since that reads as "A reduces to B" which is natural. In RTL languages, I don't know what's the convention: if you feel that $B \leq A$ would read in a natural way as "A reduces to B" in your RTL language, you probably should use that convention, I guess. If maths books use to write something like (reversed English) "$f(5+x)+g(x)=h(x)$ as $h$ define us let", then it looks as a good idea.

Comment: @Daruissoli, what does it mean by the character sequence, "$x \lt y$" in Farsi?  Is it "x is smaller than y" or "y is smaller than x"? Is the syntax correct at all? I recommend you to include the background about Farsi in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $A \le_pB$ means problem $A$ can be reduced to problem $B$ in polynomial time, and that $B$ is at least as hard as $A$, because solving $B$ means solving $A$.

$A \le_pB$ $\equiv$ $B \ge_pA$

It does $\mathbf{not}$, however, mean $B \le_pA$, and to claim as much you would have to show the appropriate reduction.